# Guide for implementing oAuth2 authenticated calls to an api

Tags: oauth-2.0, middleware, azure-ad-b2c

I have developer an API that is secured by oAuth2 and Azure B2C.  I now want to access that API from a legacy web forms application which is using Forms as it's authentication mechanism.

I have used hellojs successfully on the client side to trigger the authentication method in a separate browser window and then use the access token successfully to call my API but how do i do this from the server side?

All the examples I've seen when setting up oAuth2 involve securing an API using the OWIN middleware (e.g. with Facebook login, etc) but I need to retain the existing forms authentication and simply invoke code that calls the API and handles the access code/token etc.

If I need the backend system to make requests on behalf of a user, should I be storing the access token securely somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to have the users authenticate against B2C separately. Think of this in terms of "linking" their account in your Web Forms app to their B2C account. If you also request the `offline_access` from Azure B2C, you'll receive a Refresh Token that you can exchange for a valid Access Token when needed.

Ideally, you should pivot away from Forms authentication. It's a very outdated model. It may, however, be a non-trivial amount of work which is why many folks often choose to start with the "linking" strategy and only tackle Forms Auth when they're doing a larger refactoring of their app.

Comment: I have upgraded to OWIN Claims-Based Forms Authentication to reduce impact on the application but this has allowed me to configure external authentication as well.  However, the biggest challenge is dealing with the fact that most examples assume you want to authenticate your application with the external provider whereas all I want to do is acccess it's API.  I have therefore also implemented MSAL to call my Azure protected API.